# Why does my avocado seedling have just a tall stalk with no leaves?

Tags: diagnosis, seedlings, avocado

I've planted an avocado seed in dirt and it has begun to grow, only there are no leaves: just a skinny tall stalk.

Any idea as to why the leaves are not growing?

Comment: It takes a little while before the leaves appear.  How long have you had a shoot?   Also, how big is your pot?  The root gets big fast.  I've got one going following the advice in "the pip book recently.

Comment: Please send pictures...don't worry about the root getting too big too fast.  Too small of a plant for a large pot is not good.  What are you using for fertilizer?  Soil?  Is this in a pot or in your garden soil?

Answer (score 3):

Most likely something is eating the leaves.

If the plant is small (less then 6" / 15cm or so, it the leaves would possibly be very small and still folded.